# Makefile compute new version of each folder

Tags: bash, makefile

I have got a tree structure like this :

```
upperfolder 
│
└───1
│   │   output_v1.xml
│   │   output_v2.xml
│   
└───2
│   │   output_v1.xml
│   
└───3
```

and i would like to goes to this :

```
upperfolder 
│
└───1
│   │   output_v1.xml
│   │   output_v2.xml
│   │   output_v3.xml
│   
└───2
│   │   output_v1.xml
│   │   output_v2.xml
│   
└───3
│   │   output_v1.xml
```

I use a makefile to do this and it looks like this :

```
./upperfolder/%:
    --- here i would like to grab the last version of each folder % , incremente it and ---
    --- compute next version name file to put it in parameters of my python script      ---
    python3 writer.py <previous_version_path_script> $@_v?.xml


all: ./upperfolder/1/output ./upperfolder/2/output ./upperfolder/3/output ./upperfolder/4/output
```

Indeed my python script need 2 entries :
1) The path of previous version xml file
2) The path  of new version xml file

I tried to eval variables fetching the last char of pwd of target (that is the number of folder since we can't grab the % value in target (grrrrrrrrrr)) like this :

```
$(eval number := $(shell basename $@))
```

But i'm not really satisfied because let's imagine the folder name is not a simple number but something+number, i would need to fetch the last char of it. So i'm pretty sure there exists a better way to do it. Concerning the last version of each folder, to be honest i don't have any idea how i could do it.

Help or ints would be really appreciated

Comment: I find this question unclear. What does the Python script *do?* Does it create a new file? Does it modify the old file? Does it merely rename a file? What do you mean by "version of a folder"? What is the significance (if there is any) of the numbers in the file names?

Comment: Sorry to answer late, indeed the idea was to take the last version of each folder and thanks to this file modify it to create a new version. Typically in the xml it could be just an element contening an integer and the python script is aimed to increase it for each version. But i guess make is not the tool suited for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use make to do this.

Makefiles require that you know what the final thing you want to build is.  That final file is the target that make will try to build: it starts with that target and works *backward* find the things needed to build it.  It can visualize what kinds of things you might need to build a given target, **but** you have to give it a target: it can't visualize *forward* from an existing file to some new file that it doesn't know about.

In your case you can't write down in your makefile what the final targets you want to build are, because they aren't static: the name of final target depends on the existing files.

Also, make's entire reason for existing is to *avoid* updating files if they already exist and are up to date.  In your case you always want to create a new file, so it's not of any use to use make to try to avoid building something.

You would have to write a script that figures out what the current version is, then generates a new version from that.  At that point it seems useless to even involve make: just have your script run the python command to generate the file.

In short, `make` is simply the wrong tool for the job you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty clear and I started understanding that it was not the good tool to achieve when it blowed my mind just thinking about it. But what do you think it would be better ? .sh, another .py ?

Comment: It's up to you: whatever tool you feel most comfortable using.  I don't see any great advantages to one over the other.  Using shell is very portable among POSIX systems and doesn't require extra software to be installed.  But on the other hand Python is more easily portable to non-POSIX systems, and if you already need it anyway to run the build there's no reason not to use it here as well.